# UIButton inside UISegmentedControl action

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, uisegmentedcontrol

I am continuing my calculation program to improve my skills in Swift code. Right now I have a problem: I want that an UISegmentedControl select the operator of my operations (+, - ecc..) and when one is selected a UIButton func calculate the values based on the decision of the UISegmentedControl.

Here is the code but is not working.

Thanks,
Matteo

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var firstNumber: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var secondNumber: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var resultButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var resultNumber: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var operatorSelector: UISegmentedControl!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func operatorSelectorChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    switch operatorSelector.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        @IBAction func resultFunction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
            if let firstNumberConv :Int = Int(firstNumber.text!), let secondNumberConv :Int = Int(secondNumber.text!) {
                let result = firstNumberConv + secondNumberConv
                resultNumber.text = "\(result)"
            } else { resultNumber.text = "Inserire solo valori numerici"}
        }


    case 1:
        @IBAction func resultFunction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
            if let firstNumberConv :Int = Int(firstNumber.text!), let secondNumberConv :Int = Int(secondNumber.text!) {
                let result = firstNumberConv - secondNumberConv
                resultNumber.text = "\(result)"
            } else { resultNumber.text = "Inserire solo valori numerici"}
        }

    default:
        break;

    }

}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the lines with `@IBAction func ...` inside your switch cases.

I think your `@IBAction func operatorSelectorChanged` should look something like this:

```
@IBAction func operatorSelectorChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    switch operatorSelector.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        if let firstNumberConv = Int(firstNumber.text!), let secondNumberConv = Int(secondNumber.text!) {
            let result = firstNumberConv + secondNumberConv
            resultNumber.text = "\(result)"
        } else { resultNumber.text = "Inserire solo valori numerici"}


    case 1:
        if let firstNumberConv = Int(firstNumber.text!), let secondNumberConv = Int(secondNumber.text!) {
            let result = firstNumberConv - secondNumberConv
            resultNumber.text = "\(result)"
        } else { resultNumber.text = "Inserire solo valori numerici"}

    default:
        break;

    }

}
```

Comment: as expected nothing happen when click the button because no action is done when the button is pressed. I think the @IBAction must remain. By the way thank you very much for helping...what else we can do?

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint on the line `switch operatorSelector.selectedSegmentIndex {` and see if it gets executed when you change the segment?

Comment: You say "above" the breakpoint. Do you mean that the `@IBAction ...` becomes green or the `switch ...` line itself?

Comment: switch line when click on "case 1", otherwise by default no.

Comment: OK and when you click on the "step over" button after the line gets green, what happens then? step over button is: http://i.stack.imgur.com/b4Mbc.png

Comment: So the green line doesn't disappear?

Comment: no, it go on but nothing happen on app.I can't understand how something can happen if non action is called...

Comment: `@IBAction func` denotes a function that can be called by performing some user interaction (like clicking a button). Once such function is called, all the satements inside this function will be evaluated. There is no need to put @IBAction before each statement in this function.

Comment: yes, there are two different action to make. 1 is select the operator on UiSegmented and the click on a Button to get the result. So I think I need two IBAction since there are two elements that make two different things, but one is dipendent to another one.

Comment: OK now I see the problem :) I will post another answer

Comment: great! I hope I have express myself well this time..:)

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution for your problem is to define an IBAction that calculates the result of adding/subtracting two numbers

```
@IBAction func calculate(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if let a = Int(firstNumber.text!), let b = IntsecondNumber.text!) {
        switch operatorSelector.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            resultNumber.text = "\(a+b)"
        case 1:
            resultNumber.text = "\(a-b)"
        default:
            print("❗️unknown operator selected")
        }
    }
}
```

You could then bind this action to the sent events from your user interface: for example the `Editing Changed` event of your text fields (firstNumber and secondNumber) and the `Value Changed` of your segmented control (operatorSelector)

I created an example project that illustrates this: https://github.com/dev1an/calculator

---

### How to bind multiple events to one IBAction

Write down the IBAction in code (like the calculate action I wrote above). Go to your storyboard and open the assistent editor (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>). Select a UI element (like a text field) in the interface builder. Open the Connections Inspector (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>6</kbd>) and drag from the circle next to a sent event (for example Editing Changed) to your IBAction code.

Comment: i cannot understand How to bind. Looks like it is not working for me. When I connect circle no more code is added.

Comment: That's OK, it should not add any code since the code is already written down. "Connecting the circle" like you said, is connecting the event to some code inside your @IBAction func(...) {...}. When a user now causes an event to fire, the code that is connected to this event will be executed.